# Socket output stream with DataOuputStream - what are the guarantees?

Tags: java, sockets, exception

Looking at the code:

```
private static void send(final Socket socket, final String data) throws IOException {
    final OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
    dos.writeUTF(data);
    dos.flush();
}
```

can I be sure that calling this method either throws `IOException` (and that means that I'd better close the socket), or, if no exceptions are thrown, the data I send is guaranteed to be fully send? Are there any cases when I read the data on the other endpoint, the string I get is incomplete and there are no exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between sent and received.  You can send data from the application successfully, however it then passes to

- the OS on your machine
- the network adapter
- the switch(s) on the network
- the network adapter on the remote machine
- the OS on the remote machine
- the application buffer on the remote machine
- whatever the application does with it.

Any of these stages can fail and your sender will be none the wiser.

If you want to know the application has received and processed the data successfully, it must send you back a message saying this has happened.  When you receive this, then you know it was received.

Comment: Except for the last two points, TCP should handle it, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well, the idea is - I need to send a string from one endpoint to another. What's right approach here to make sure that the data received is at least "complete"? Is it possible that I send "HELLO" and only receive "HELL"?

Comment: TCP will do its best but there is no guarantee in the event of a failure, and the sender still won't get an exception.

Comment: If you use readUTF() and the string is not complete the *receiver* will get an EOFException. If the reciever reads one byte at a time, it is possible it can see 'H' 'E' 'L' 'L', but it can also determine that the string was incomplete as the length is send first.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Thanks! So I can rely on `readUTF()` at least for either getting the complete data or an exception.

Comment: Unless your application dies of course, in which case you get nothing and the data is lost. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, several things may happen. First of all, keep in mind `write` **returns really quickly**, so don't think much error checking (has all my data been ACKed ?) is performed.

#### Door number 1

You `write` and `flush` your data. `TCP` tries as hard as it can to deliver it. Which means it might perform retransmits and such. Of course, your `send` doesn't get stuck for such a long period (in some cases `TCP` tries for 5-10 minutes before it nukes the connections). Thus, you will never know if the other side actually got your message. You will get an error message on the next operation on the socket.

#### Door number 2

You `write` and `flush` your data. Because of [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) nastiness and because the string is long, it is sent in multiple packets. So your peer `reads` some of it and presents it to the user before getting it all.

So imagine you send: **"Hello darkness my old friend, I've come to talk with you again"**. The other side might get *"Hello darkness m"*. However, if it performs subsequent `read`s, it will get the whole data. So the far side TCP has actually received everything, it has ACKed everything but the user application has failed to `read` the data in order to take it out of TCPs hands.

Comment: That's confusing. `writeUTF()` encodes the data in a Length-Data way, so `readUTF()` should rely on it. If there's a string of 20 bytes and you know it and then only receive 10 bytes, I believe `readUTF()` should block unless other 10 bytes arrive or, if it takes too long, it should throw. Wrong?

Comment: @loki2302 If the reading method has any means of knowing the length it is supposed to receive, of course if will block until it gets all of it.